# Network port is occupied, but there is no processuse it

Tags: linux, networking

My 4000 port is occupied, however, I want to kill the process which occupy it. When I use `netstat -anp | grep 4000` However the result is:

```
$ netstat -anp | grep 4000
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

When I use `lsof -i:4000`, I got nothing, so the process which ever owned the port 4000 died, the port 4000 is still  not released?

How to solve it?

Comment: What did you see whe you ran it as `root` as advised?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: when I ran it as `root` I can see the process id.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the notification said, when I ran `netstat` in a normal user, `non-owned process info will not be shown`. So using `sudo netstat`, you will see the process id.